# Salesforce Development and configuration

Tags: salesforce-service-cloud

I want to merge 6 different profiles into one, consolidating  FLS, Record Type, Permission sets, Page layouts in salesforce. May I know whats the best possible and easiest way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Salesforce Metadata API to retrieve the 6 profiles in xml form. You can then view all the permissions each profile has and consolidate into one. Then use the Metadata API deploy() to deploy the profile to your Salesforce org.

Salesforce give examples on how to retrieve profiles and the required package.xml to include in the request here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm

Note: the retrieval content of profiles is relative. i.e to see the profile permissions for Account object, you must include the Account object in your retrieve request.

Salesforce documentation:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/file_based.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm